# What detects and raises the common exceptions like DivideByZero, StackEmpty etc. when there is no try-catch?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, runtime

I want to know where do these exceptions get raised, where does the validation occur which raises them. I know it happens at runtime and programming language does it internally but which library does it in c# or in any other language.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://airbrake.io/blog/dotnet-exception-handling/dividebyzeroexception)

Comment: @JeroenHeier Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -2):

> C# exceptions are represented by classes. The exception classes in C# are mainly directly or indirectly derived from the System.Exception class. Some of the exception classes derived from the ***System.Exception*** class are the ***System.ApplicationException*** and ***System.SystemException*** classes.
>
> The ***System.ApplicationException*** class supports exceptions generated by application programs. Hence the exceptions defined by the programmers should derive from this class.
>
> The ***System.SystemException*** class is the base class for all predefined system exception.

know more about predefined exception classes derived from the Sytem.SystemException class 
here:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_exception_handling.htm

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question. Also the distinction between ApplicationException and SystemException is outdated and not used by Microsoft anymore. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.applicationexception?view=netframework-4.8) explicitly state that you should neither derive your exceptions from ApplicationException nor throw them, which means that your source is wrong on this issue.